# How to force the /~username on URLs for cPanel temporary URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel

Installing some stuff on a cPanel temporary URL, example: ip.add.ress/~username

The links to CSS, JS files in the code and hrefs, etc ... drop the /~username from the URL.

Is there a way using a .htaccess file to force the username to the URL?

Example

/my-includes/css.css

/my-includes/js.js

Get:

/~username/my-includes/css.css

/~username/my-includes/js.js

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes that can done using this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(my-includes/.+)$ /~username/$1 [L,NC,NE,R]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are the server owner you can do this through WHM Home »Security Center »Apache mod_userdir Tweak where you can enable or disable the security feature to disable mod_userdir.  Because of this approach this configuration may be confusing.  You will want to have the Mod_userdir protection disabled for all users on your server to be able to use ~username

You can also turn on this protection disabling mod_userdir, and then exclude specific users from this protection.

Please see:  http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/TweakModuserdir

Answer (score 0):

This an old question, but you also need to ensure that the PHP handler is `suphp`, not `cgi`.  I have multiPHP enabled and leave PHP7 on `cgi` but also have PHP56 but on `suphp`.

Also, be sure to exclude the particular user in the mod_userdir tweak.